# Pandas: How to write the path (of where data is) in Linux and windows

Tags: python, linux, pandas, ubuntu

I have data stored in a folder in a drive that Windows 7 knows as Drive E.
I have dual boot, windows and Linux (ubuntu)
My data in Linux is in a folder under /media/username/AC3267F63267C3C4/foldername

In Windows I would write:

```
from os import path
df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join("e:/", "Datasets", "datafolder", "datafile.csv"))
```

But in Linux, for the same source data, what should I use? I can't use drive E right? And if I need to /media/username/AC3267F63267C3C4/foldername
what is the point of having os.path? because it was supposed to be cross platform.
So how do I access the same data source in Linux?

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/350458/passing-a-file-location-to-python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350458/passing-a-file-location-to-python)

Comment: The very concept of "a drive letter" does not exist outside of Windows world. The idea that the user should be aware of the physical layout of his storage in his everyday use is silly.

Answer (score 1):

*Possible solution*. You can use the platform module to detect the OS.

```
import platform
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join("e:/", "Datasets", "datafolder", "datafile.csv"))
else:
    df = pandas.read_csv("/media/username/AC3267F63267C3C4/foldername/datafile.csv")
```